# pass values to tiles

Tags: struts2, tiles

without using tiles,this is ok.

```
<action name="/books/{ISBN}/content" class="example.BookAction">
    <result>/books/{1}.jsp</result>
</action>
```

i try to get this using tiles, but values were not passed to the tiles definition 
here is my code:

```
<action name="/books/{ISBN}/content" class="example.BookAction">
    <result type="tiles">{1}blablabla</result>
</action>
```

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="*blablabla" extends="main_layout">
   <put-attribute name="body_area" value="/books/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

how can i do this? thanks.!!

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong but here is a complete example using a rather current version of tiles 2.2.2 with some nice features including wild card support and OGNL support (not shown in the example is there is also regex support): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050433/ognl-and-wildcards-working-in-tiles-definitions-with-struts2-tiles-plugin

Comment: hmm..i think there is a tiles version problem here.i've been using  2.1.2. thank you friend.

Comment: The answer covers the required jars, you need to manually upgrade tiles dependencies but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards. In struts xml

```
<action name="/books/{ISBN}/content" class="example.BookAction">
    <result type="tiles">${evalExpression}blablabla</result>
</action>
```

and then in tiles

```
<definition name="*blablabla" extends="main_layout">
   <put-attribute name="body_area" value="/books/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```