# Struts2 tiles org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener integration error

Tags: struts2, tiles

I am following answer posted here. [OGNL and wildcards working in tiles definitions with struts2-tiles-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050433/ognl-and-wildcards-working-in-tiles-definitions-with-struts2-tiles-plugin/10067367#10067367)

*If you know the answer, would apprecite if you tell me how to use freemarker with it. If don't even than I accept the answer if you solve my problem to make the code work.*

Everything is same but

```
Struts2 & Tiles plugin - 2.3.4.1
```

**pom.xml**

1.6
    UTF-8
    3.1.2.RELEASE
    2.3.4.1
    1.6.6
    2.2.2

```
<!-- Start Extras -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- End Extras -->

<!-- Start sl4j dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- End sl4j dependencies -->

<!-- Start Struts2 dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- End struts2 dependencies -->

<!-- Start Tiles dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- End Tiles dependencies -->
```

**ERROR**

```
Oct 29, 2012 9:51:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tiles.el.JspExpressionFactoryFactory.getExpressionFactory(JspExpressionFactoryFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.createELEvaluator(CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.java:268)
    at org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.createAttributeEvaluatorFactory(CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.java:204)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Oct 29, 2012 9:51:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 29, 2012 9:51:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/2_Sruts2_Tiles_JSP] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**pom dependencies**

[image: mvn]

**Web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**EDITED VERSION :**

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Struts2_Old_Tiles_JSP_Freemarker</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Struts2_Old_Tiles_JSP_Freemarker WebApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Struts2_Old_Tiles_JSP_Freemarker</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>

    <package name="basicstruts2" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" default="true" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <action name="/**" class="com.kenmcwilliams.tiles.action.Test">
            <result>{1}</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Default Title"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/body.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="variable" expression="OGNL:greeting"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="test" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Test Title"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="WILDCARD:package/*" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/test.ftl"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="" extends="baseLayout">
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Conclusion**

if you use it with Glassfish as tested with the code is working fine **BUT**

After alot of testing and checking, the problem is with embedded tomcat7 instance which is not working with the above web.xml configuration and genertating error. Below is the `pom.xml` plugin that if run tomcat7:run will generate the error. Not sure whats the problem.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8000</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I just upgraded my example application (which was used to create the example which you link to)... I'm not sure what changed and I don't know how to fix it at this time.

Comment: have u put listener in web.xml ??

Comment: @ashish-gupta, Yes. See my question added my web.xml at the end.

Comment: @quaternion, now I am stuck :( . I want to integrate tiles with freemarker as my target.

Comment: The fastest solution would be to revert to 2.3.1.2 (both struts2-core and struts2-tiles-plugin) since something breaks after the upgrade. Oh and complain, to the struts2-tiles-plugin maintainer!

Comment: @quaternion, ok Thanks. Do you know any online tutorial to work with Struts2+Tiles+FreeMarker?. Can not make it to work.

Comment: Well there is one here now =)... better here than someplace else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: The following has been tested to work (struts2 with tiles 2.2.2 and freemarker). Due to time constraints this solution works with struts2 2.3.1.2 and the struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.1.2 but NOT higher versions. Tried 2.3.4.1 and something broke.

Set up the following: [OGNL and wildcards working in tiles definitions with struts2-tiles-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050433/ognl-and-wildcards-working-in-tiles-definitions-with-struts2-tiles-plugin/10067367#10067367)

**Add freemarker support for tiles:**

**Artifact**: tiles-freemarker,
**Group**: org.apache.tiles,
**Version**: 2.2.2

**Extending the test from the previous example to incorporate a freemarker title into the demo:**
Add `/WEB-INF/content/tiles/test.ftl` which contains:

```
<#assign s=JspTaglibs["/struts-tags"] /> 
<@s.textfield name="test"/>
```

One line has been added to tiles.xml `<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/test.ftl"/>` under the `WILDCARD:package/*` definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Default Title"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/body.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="variable"  expression="OGNL:greeting"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="test" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Test Title"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="WILDCARD:package/*" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/tiles/test.ftl"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="" extends="baseLayout">
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Test it**:

My applicaton context is `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Tiles2_2_2Example/` appending `package/bla` we have `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Tiles2_2_2Example/package/bla`and we will see a text field rendered by velocity incorporated into the view, and the title bar will say 'bla'.

**Edit** new content:

**pom**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kenmcwilliams</groupId>
    <artifactId>Struts2Tiles2_2_2Example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Struts2Tiles2_2_2Example</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Changed struts2 version but still same error. Can you add your pom.xml to see whats wrong please. What do you think about this solution for Struts2+Tiles+FreeMarker integration? http://sooin01.tistory.com/entry/Struts2-Tiles2-Freemarker-%EC%84%A4%EC%A0%95

Comment: I don't have time to read it but their web.xml looks more complicated than necessary. I'll provide pom and web.xml.

Comment: I just glanced at the example but they are are also using tiles wildcards, that method does not allow for the evaluation of ognl expressions within tiles. It does show integration but it isn't as integrated as we might like. The extra level of functionality means that expressions need to be prefixed to understand how they are evaluated ie. : WILDCARD:package/* and OGNL:greeting

Comment: I have tried my best. Followed whatever you have posted but still getting that error posted in question. I have added my current project info in the question and taged it Edited Version. Please see if you can help.

Comment: Put your email on your profile and I'll just email you the project, I will not have the opportunity until tonight(probably 7h from now). In exchange, if you could identity the issue that prevented success so we can make the question clear that would be great =)

Comment: added my email at the end of question. Will remove it as soon as you post here that you emailed me. I don't know how to enable email on profile

Comment: I have started jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES-561 . Please follow if possible.

Comment: Can't be sure but I doubt it is a problem with tiles, most likely it is a problem with the plugin. I might get around to checking what changed between versions.

Comment: ok see if you can solve this and I mark it as answer. I have spent many hrs, googled etc but no luck. Oh and email me project please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18830/discussion-between-quaternion-and-rashid)

Comment: In the end read my conclusion added at the end of question. Good luck and thanks for all the help. Post if you find solution to work with embedded tomcat7 instance.

Comment: I was slightly motivated by your question to explore tiles 3 and integration with the latest struts2. The result is a new result type, I am still working on it (it is very trivial).  But is does currently render a tiles result from a struts2 action just want to test a bit more. It should have all the features of the tiles 2.2.2 integration. Since the solution builds without warnings/errors I don't think it will cause issues.

Comment: Tiles 3.0.1 is in beta? . Any answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242649/tiles-templates-insertattribute-not-working-in-ftl-freemarker

Comment: That's interesting, I have little experience with freemarker outside of tests... I'll make it a test a bit latter to see if tiles 3.0.1 has any issues with it. I don't think tiles 3 is beta, don't know about tiles 3.0.1 but the plugin works against tiles 3 and higher I am just trying to use the latest and greatest because I'm sick of trying to get older versions working. So far my experience has been very good.

Comment: for Tiles 3.0.0 same pom used for 2.2.2 with extras is not working. I think some dependencies may be needed?. 3.0.0 working fine for you?

Comment: No, anything higher will not work without a different tiles-plugin, creating such a plug in is pretty easy. I'll test and then use it to answer you other question